# From train test split to cross validation in sklearn using pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation

I have the following piece of code:

```
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
...
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= model_selection.train_test_split(dataframe[features_],dataframe[labels], test_size=0.30,random_state=42, shuffle=True)
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=11)
pipe = Pipeline([('feats', feature), ('clf', classifier)])
pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)
predicts = pipe.predict(x_test)
```

Instead of train test split, I want to use k-fold cross validation to train my model. However, I do not know how can make it by using pipeline structure. I came across this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html but I could not fit to my code.

I want to use `from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold` if possible. I can use it without pipeline structure but I can not use it with pipeline.

Update:
I tried this but it generates me error.

```
x_train = dataframe[features_]
y_train = dataframe[labels]

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=42) 
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=11)
     
#pipe = Pipeline([('feats', feature), ('clf', classifier)])
#pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)
#predicts = pipe.predict(x_test)

predicts = cross_val_predict(classifier, x_train , y_train , cv=skf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pipeline` is used to assemble several steps such as preprocessing, transformations, and modeling. `StratifiedKFold` is used to split your dataset to assess the performance of your model. It is not meant to be used as a part of the `Pipeline` as you do not want to perform it on new data.

Therefore it is normal to perform it out of the pipeline's structure.

Comment: I tried what you said but probably there is a mistake. I updated my post, could you please take a look at it

Comment: The cv parameter is expecting an int value or an iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.

Answer (score 2):

While I echo with the answer provided above, below might be the code you are looking for:

```
    x_train = dataframe[features_]
    y_train = dataframe[labels]
    
    pipe = Pipeline([('feats', feature), ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=11))])
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3,  shuffle=True, random_state=42)      

    predicts = cross_val_predict(pipe, x , y , scoring='accuracy',cv=skf, n_jobs = -1, error_score = 'raise')
```

Since you are using Cross validation, train_test_split() is not required to be passed to the Pipeline, the cross validation split (i.e., the training sample) is passed directly to the pipeline for feature extraction and modeling and evaluated on the test set (which is also generated as part of the cv split)